# Change default collation in WampServer

Tags: mysql, wamp, wordpress

I have just installed WampServer (x64) in order to install a WordPress site. In `localhost/phpmyadmin/` the  Server connection collation is  `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

When I created a new DB, I defined the collation to be 'utf8_general_ci'

However, when I installed the wordpress I looked back in my DB and all the tables are in collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

Why this was happened?

I tried and in `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\my.ini` file under the tag `[mysqld]` I added the:

```
character-set-server=utf8    
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Then I restarted the wampserver, I installed the wordpress from scratch and again all the tables has Collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If it's the [server connection collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) it could be different from the collation that is actually used in the background. What's the reason that you want to make that change? As for your approach it's correct. You could [check](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation) an individual DB or Table for it's actual collation. [This](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32105) would make `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` seem to be a better choice?

Comment: The problem started when I tried to migrate the website to server which didn't support utf8mb4.. So they told me to change the collation to utf8_general..

Comment: But that is a totally different problem from what you described? If you did a migration did you check your SQL files for a fixed setting of the collation?

Comment: I am a newbie so I am afraid I don't know what do you mean exactly.. what should I do;

Comment: For your migration you probably exported the existing database in some form using phpMyAdmin or mysqldump? Right? In that case you ended up with a `.sql` file which is just a normal text file. You could just replace lines that mention `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with ones that have whatever character set or collation you want or drop those all together to use the server default. Though that would involve some risk as for the stuff you have in your DB, depending on what it is.

Comment: well this exactly I did! However, now that I am building a new site I wanted to avoid this.. To export my DB, I do it from phpmyadmin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define collations in multiple places. As discussed in the comments your MySQL server version supports setting the collation on a connection level.

To see whenever you modified the correct configuration you could run a simple `CREATE TABLE` statement like the following and check which charset and collation it would be using.

```
CREATE TABLE testSettings(
  Dummy TEXT
);
```

You didn't specify the WP version but you might try setting the `char` and `collation` to use using the [configuration file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Database_collation) [[2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/)]. On the current WP version (4.7.1) the default seems to be to set the `charset` to `utf8` and not define a `collation`. You will have to test whenever setting the collation in the confguration would prevent the change.

But even if you do that I'm not sure it would save your hide as ([since 2015 at least](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/)) WP is silently upgrading the collation to `utf8mb4`. If that information is not enough you could also look at [this closed bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32105) which might shine some light on the decision.

A way to circumvent the upgrade would be to use an older MySQL version. But looking at [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) I would suggest just changing the service that is running your DB. If they don't support `utfmb4` it seems they're running a MySQL server that is older than [5.5.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html) which was released in March **2010**. Which would indicate that they didn't update their software for more than 6 years.